# MVC: How to Use Same selected item for two diff drop downList in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using same selected item for two diff Drop down list. Below is the view code.

```
<div id="divSelectingItem1" class="editor-field">
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LocationOne)
  @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedLocation)
      .DataTextField("Text").DataValueField("Value")
      .BindTo(Model.LocationOne)
      .Value(Model.SelectedLocation))         
</div>


<div id="divSelectingItem2" class="editor-field">
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LocationTwo)
  <span id="spnObsDateTimeIcon" class="k-icon k-i-note"></span>
  @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedLocation)
      .DataTextField("Text").DataValueField("Value")
      .BindTo(Model.LocationTwo)
      .Value(Model.SelectedLocation))
</div>
```

### Model class

```
public class LocationViewModel :ViewModelBase
{
    [DisplayName("Identifier Location")]
    public List<SelectListItem> LocationOne{ get; set; }
    public string SelectedLocation{ get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Identifier Location")]
    public List<SelectListItem> LocationTwo{ get; set; }

}
```

But the above code is not working.. Am i making any mistake? I am new to .net MVC any help...

Comment: How come do you have `SelectedLocation` defined twice in `LocationViewModel`?

Comment: yes you are correct that was mistake.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the binding to properly work I think you have to give the drop-down element the same name as the model property is should be bound to.

```
<div id="divSelectingItem1" class="editor-field">
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LocationOne)
  @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedLocation)
      .Name("SelectedLocation") //<--Name of the model property 
      .DataTextField("Text").DataValueField("Value")
      .BindTo(Model.LocationOne)
      .Value(Model.SelectedLocation))         
</div>
```

I don't think you can use the bound model way with two elements representing the same property. I think if you tried would run into js errors. If the variables did make it make it back to your controller then I bet the `SelectedLocation` would be the value of the first drop-down list.

One way to work around this would be to give the drop downs a unique name and then save them when you are ready to send the data. But you would still need two properties.

It sounds like you want a default value in which case something like the following would work:

```
<div id="divSelectingItem1" class="editor-field">
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LocationOne)
  @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedLocationOne)
      .Name("SelectedLocationOne") //<--Name of the model property 
      .DataTextField("Text").DataValueField("Value")
      .BindTo(Model.LocationOne)
      .Value(Model.DefaultSelectedLocation))         
</div>



<div id="divSelectingItem2" class="editor-field">
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LocationTwo)
  <span id="spnObsDateTimeIcon" class="k-icon k-i-note"></span>
  @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedLocationTwo)
      .Name("SelectedLocationTwo")
      .DataTextField("Text").DataValueField("Value")
      .BindTo(Model.LocationTwo)
      .Value(Model.DefaultSelectedLocation))
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, You are correct If i put .Name then its work. But when i save other item then also its shows the first item. Is there any way to map the .Name("SelectedLocationOne")  with the Selected properties (SelectedLocationOne)

Comment: The .Value() only gives the drop-down it's default value. When you bind to to your Model using DropDownListFor() and .Name("") you shouldn't bind two elements to one property. You need to create MyObject.SelectedLocation1 and MyObject.SelectedLocation2. Are you trying to create create a List<MyObject> where MyObject has SelectedLocation?